# How to rename a protobuf msg? typedef like C/C++?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I defined the following protobuf message A and B:

```
message A {
    optional int32 err_code = 1;
    optional string err_msg = 2;
}
message B {
    optional int32 err_code = 1;
    optional string err_msg = 2;
}
```

Can I directly use B as an alias for A?

If I can't do it, how to gracefully copy an A message instance to a B message instance?

Looking forward to your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're 3 ways to do that:

1. Copy field by field from `A` to `B`: `a.err_code = b.err_code; *(a.mutable_err_msg()) = b.err_msg();` The code is tedious.
2. Use reflection to copy fields in a loop without explicitly assign one field to another. You need to learn about reflection mechanism.
3. You can serialize `A` to a string, and deserialize the string to `B`. It might not be very efficiency.

```
A a;
std::string s;
a.SerializeToString(&s);

B b;
b.ParseFromString(s);
```